# New ddr3 ram sticks won't work with motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply

So I brought 2 new ddr3 sticks which my motherboard uses, but when I put them in, the power supply just has 1 constant beep, meaning that the ram sticks aren't working, is this a fault with the sticks or did I make a mistake with which sticks to buy?

Also, when I put my old ddr3 sticks back in, it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the power supply is making the sound since that would be extremely unlikely.  Power Supplies don’t typically have speakers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The only way to tell would be to buy the same RAM model/make again and try them.